# what is the best way to init var with max value?

Tags: android, performance, iterator

inside the loop i use

```
if(x>myMaxValue)myMaxValue = x;
```

i have been told to change it to :

```
myMaxValue = Math.max(x, myMaxValue);
```

what is considered to be better way to do this ? i understand the difference is minor .

Comment: Your naming convention seems backwards, are you sure you have the variables the right way around? Seem you are applying a minimum value type of logic

Comment: He isn't. He's setting myMaxValue to a larger value. However, it's always better to not reinvent the wheel. Also, the second version is more concise because it displays not only function, but also intent, which is important.

Comment: The first version isn't as good in terms of code style/readability

Comment: ctrl+click on Math.max, you'll see the implementation, which is basically what you already do. It is more a matter of readability.

Comment: no need to down vote guys (-:  , thanks @njzk2 for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They only differ in readability, the Math.max() approach is more clear.